# Call script when site is opened

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, startup

How to let a script start as soon as the site is loaded?
I want the Website content i have to fade in, but didn't find an event for "when site open" yet.

And basically, on the site you can switch betweent two "contents". Im only as far as the first "content" to fadeOut on button press, but wanted the things above to be done first.

I tried to use a CSS animation, but then there is no fade effect, so the "content" disapears after a few seconds. Here the code i want to use:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#main").fadeOut(200);
    });
});
</script>
```

And that part of the code works just fine. So, can anybody help me or find another solution?

Comment: `$(document).ready()` is triggered when the DOM has loaded. Is this not doing what you need it to? It would also help to post your code in a JSfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function defined inside `$document.ready()` is called when the page loads.  Just make sure that the item you are trying to fade is hidden by default (`display:none` will work in css).

To make sure that the fadeout of your first section is finished before your second section starts fading in, try using the [setTimeout() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).  Remember to set the `display:none` attribute for your second section.

```
$('#main button').click(function(){
    $("#main").fadeOut(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#secondary").fadeIn(1000);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Check out this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jtbricker/pen/wMQKoW) for an example of this all together.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful pen and good explanation! I planted my whole code into a pen too, because something didnt work on my website. But in the pen it doesnt work too... If you got any idea please tell me. Here's the link (yes im quite new to HMTL and CSS, have not bothered to learn jQuery or whatever yet) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyzwGm. It's a project I'm doing for an agar.io clan, so some comments in the HTML or CSS files may not make sense to you :P

Comment: Might have to mention a few things: The button that should open the secondary content is the button saying "Open Beta". Overall that was my idea: The page gets opened, main fades in, "Open Beta" gets clicked, main fades out and main2 (name in the pen) fades in...

Comment: Okay, I've taken a look at your codePen (looks nice, btw) and I've come up with a few problems with your code:  1) You do not have JQuery loaded (click on the setting on the Javascript tab and add the Jquery Library).  2)  You need to initially have your main1 span hidden (`display:none`) in order for it to fade in.  3)  Your javascript assigns the click event to `#main button` but you do not have a button tag, you have a link with id/class "button"  so your javascript should be targeting `#main #button` .   After I made those changes you code worked.

Comment: Thanks! Everything seems to work... except that the #main2 won't fade in. Here is the updated Pen (your solutions) : [Open](http://codepen.io/Voakie/pen/OMrpwO)

Hope I don't make you too much work :)

Comment: Np problem, I'm still learning too so this type of debugging is very useful for me.  I guess I forgot to mention that your button-click triggers fadeIn of the item with ID=main2, but your 2nd page has a main2 CLASS.  Either give that span a ID=main2 (instead of class) or change the button to trigger .main2 (instead of #main2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: you mean `fadeIn` I think

Comment: A little explanation or reference to documentation would be helpful.